# Table in native app and WCAG 2,0

Tags: android, accessibility

I would like to work out what is required to make a simple standard table in a native android app compliant to **WCAG 2.0.**

I thinking about the requirement 1.3.1 Info and Relationships: Information, structure, and relationships conveyed through presentation can be programmatically determined or are available in text. (Level A)

I habe specially poblems with the requirememt of having headers in tables. I even don't know whether it is possible to reach this aim.

For a example of a simple table I took this one https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html

Thanks in  advance.

Best regards

Petra Ritter, accessibility consultant, Foundation access for all

http://www.access-for-all.ch/en/

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

Declare a Popupwindow and View as below.

`PopupWindow layoutWindow;
 View javaLayoutView;
 JavaClassName _activity = this;`

Write a Java Void method.
In this method add code below.

below will increase speed. if PopupWindow has a somthing method will not go longer else will go further.

`if(layoutWindow != null)
    return;`

Assiggn Activity to this thread.

`_activity = this;`

Calling the method from Native side will not run directly because our activity is Native Activity since. So it will execute in Ui Thread.

`this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
    // Make a Inflator Layout. Our XML Layout will work on this.
     LayoutInflater lF =
     (LayoutInflator)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    javaLayoutView = lF.inflate(R.layout.layoutfile, null);
    layoutWindow = new PopupWindow( javaLayoutView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(_activity);
    MarginLayoutParams params = new 
    MarginLayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    _activity.setContentView(mainLayout, params);
    layoutWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
    layoutWindow.update();
    }
    });`

Here your layout file will be executed on LinearLayout doesn't matter what layout you used in XML. Here by changing `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` you can change the width and height.
The line `layoutWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);` will make render your layout over Native Activity,
Remember that If you change anything after `layoutWindow.update()` must recall it to take effect.

This will damn sure work !!!